# Was Keturah Abraham's wife or concubine?

Tags: genesis, textual-discrepancies, abraham, 1-chronicles

Keturah was Abraham's wife?

> Genesis 25:1-2 Abraham had taken another wife, whose name was Keturah. She bore him Zimran, Jokshan, Medan, Midian, Ishbak and Shuah.

Keturah was Abraham's concubine?

> 1 Chronicles 1:32 The sons born to Keturah, Abraham’s concubine: Zimran, Jokshan, Medan, Midian, Ishbak and Shuah.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Please take time to take the [tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour) and browse our [help centre](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) for more info on how this site operates. Also useful is the post  [how we are different to other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites).

Comment: Please explain what the contradiction is.

Comment: It does not necessarily mean that Abraham married Keturah while Sarah was alive. A logical explanation would be that while Sarah was alive Keturah was a concubine and then Abraham married her after Sarah's death - the two facts are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: This is more of a BH question, I think.

Answer (score 1):

The difference might come down to the purpose of each book. Genesis is a literal account and since Abraham was without wife when he bound Keturah to himself--she became his wife, performing the duties of a wife.
Chronicles on the other hand is a historical record and perhaps a legal document for things such as inheritance through genealogies and also the royal lineage. So while being a technical difference between words that can mean essentially the same thing, when it comes to inheritance the difference becomes quite relevant.

This assertion is my own, but to cite a source that backs up what I say about Chronicles having genealogies [gotQuestions summary of Chronicles](https://gotquestions.org/Book-of-1-Chronicles.html) is suitable.

Another site to give perspective is from [Bible.org](https://bible.org/seriespage/4-historical-books)

> When producing the Septuagint, the translators divided Chronicles into
>   two sections. At that time it was given the title, “Of Things
>   Omitted,”

Also,

> The books of Chronicles seem like a repeat of Samuel and Kings, but
>   they were written for the returned exiles to remind them that they
>   came from the royal line of David and that they were God’s chosen
>   people. The genealogies point out that the Davidic promises had their
>   source in those pledged to Abraham that He would make him the father
>   of a great nation, one through which He would bless the nations.

As well as,

> This book also taught that the past was pregnant with lessons for
>   their present. Apostasy, idolatry, intermarriage with Gentiles, and
>   lack of unity were the reasons for their recent ruin.
>
> OUTLINE:
>
> First Chronicles naturally divides into four sections: (1) The
>   Genealogies or the Royal Line of David (1:1-9:44); (2) the Rise of
>   David or His Anointing (10:1-12:40), (3) The Reign of David
>   (13:1-29:21), and (4) The Assession of Solomon and the Death of David
>   (29:22-30).

Answer (score 0):

The word for wife in Genesis 25 could be translated as woman, according to Strong's Lexicon: http://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H802&t=KJV